# Unity wall jump issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is for a wall jump.

I basically want my wall jump to have a bit of force away from to wall to make it look and feel better than just jumping up straight.

The problem is, when I add a force on the x axis, it does not register when I am also holding the arrow towards the wall. If I am not holding down the walking button, then press jump, then the x force works.

I have a feeling that the horizontal axis force is competing with the opposite force that I want to add to the player when he hits the jump button.

Walking code:

```c
private void ApplyMovement()
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed * movementInputDirection, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (!isGrounded && !isWallSliding && movementInputDirection != 0)
    {
        Vector2 forceToAdd = new Vector2(movementForceInAir *  movementInputDirection, 0);
        myRigidbody.AddForce(forceToAdd);

        if (Mathf.Abs(myRigidbody.velocity.x) > movementSpeed)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed *  movementInputDirection, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    else if (!isGrounded && !isWallSliding && movementInputDirection == 0)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x * airDragMultiplier, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }

    if (isWallSliding)
    {
        if (myRigidbody.velocity.y < -wallSlideSpeed)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, -wallSlideSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Jump code:

```c
private void Jump()
{
    if (canJump && !isWallSliding)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        numberOfJumpsLeft--;
    }
    else if ((isWallSliding || isTouchingWall) && !isGrounded && canJump)
    {
        isWallSliding = false;
        numberOfJumpsLeft--;
        Vector2 forceToAdd = new Vector2(wallPushForce * -facingDirection, wallJumpForce *
                                         wallJumpDirection.y);
        myRigidbody.AddForce(forceToAdd, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Modifying velocity directly and adding force on the same rigidbody seems like a great way to create hard to find bugs.

Comment: do disable the forward button while wall jumping?

Comment: It's more of a game development issue than a programming issue. Wouldn't you want to post this in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: My bad on adding the (Help)... its a habit from other sites, and the first time posting to stack exchange.

I will give it a shot on gamedev.stackexchange.com... didn't know that it was a thing

Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't worry, we all make small mistakes, no big deal when we start.